# How to get instagram user profile details from userId(pk) without token or access control?

Tags: python, json, web, url-rewriting, instagram

Today itself Instagram gave user detail by using the below URL, but now it is not working.

```
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{userID}/info/
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is working now!

Answer (score 1):

Same Problem for me,

Logouts from Instagram then redirects to :

```
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/api/v1/users/{userID}/info/
```

Comment: you find any solution?

Comment: It seems that there is no way to get UserName from UserID. I just remove it from my script,

Answer (score -1):

python you need User-Agent and a login session

```
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Instagram 27.0.0.7.97 (iPhone7,2; iPhone OS 9_3_3; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 750x1334) AppleWebKit/420+'}
session = requests.Session()
"login stuff here"
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

tested and working

Comment: without access token or authentication

Comment: no ... just login info and user agent like the one i posted